# Grid ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay doesn't apply

Tags: wpf, xaml

Sorry, i found some usefull tips on StackOverFlow to set the ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay on the all application controls, but i cant find why this property doesn't apply on a single element...

Here is my code :

```
<Grid.ToolTip>
  <ToolTip ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="2000">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Treatment.TooltipText}"  ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="2000"/>
  </ToolTip>
</Grid.ToolTip>
```

And yes i tried to set the ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay on both ToolTip and TextBlock element, but nothing has changed, my ToolTip has no delay at all.

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for the record, the ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="2000" has to be placed on the Grid element, not the toolTip element nor the displayed element for ToolTip

```
<Grid ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="2000">
    ...
</Grid>
```